# SQL: Selecting Random Sample based on ID with multiple rows for each ID

Tags: sql, random, hierarchical-data

My data has the following Structure

| ID | Month | Year | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 20 | 860 |
| 1 | 2 | 20 | 22 |
| 1 | 5 | 20 | 339 |
| 2 | 3 | 20 | 12098 |
| 3 | 3 | 20 | 12 |
| 3 | 4 | 20 | 10 |
| 3 | 6 | 20 | 9 |
| 3 | 7 | 20 | 122 |
| 3 | 8 | 20 | 11 |

There are 1000s of IDs and I want to select a random sample of 100 IDs. So if I randomly select ID 3, I need all rows of data for ID 3. I have to use SQL for this. I welcome any suggestions.

Comment: If you need help with an sql statement, you should tell us the dbms you are using. Or are you referring to standardized sql? Then we should know that as well

Comment: I am using Oracle SQL Developer

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query.
For MS-Sql

```
Select top 100 * from table_name where ID=$randomId ORDER BY NEWID(); //like ID=3
```

For My-Sql

```
Select * from table_name where ID=$randomId ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 100; //like ID=3
```